# Hover texts change image wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm not a developer but i need something like in my website as image is attached. I want images change if you hover on texts.

Is there any plugin available for wp or easy method to create?

Image: (http://prntscr.com/i7kxqf)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: Sorry, didn't understood your screen shot at the first time**

You will need jQuery hover to do this :

```js
$('li').hover(function(){
  $('.image').attr('src', $(this).data('img'));
});
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 200px;
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  top: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
}

li:hover {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="image" src="https://sd-cdn.fr/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/simpsons-live.jpg">



<ul>
  <li data-img="https://sd-cdn.fr/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/simpsons-live.jpg">Img1</li>
  <li data-img="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/simpsons/images/6/63/The_Simpsons_Simpsons_FamilyPicture.png/revision/latest?cb=20101023180303">Img2</li>
  <li data-img="http://www.premiere.fr/sites/default/files/styles/premiere_article/public/thumbnails/image/simpson_horror_show.jpg">Img2</li>
</ul>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_hover.asp

Comment: Alex. thank you so much for your help. One question how do i nest these code and in which files they'll go?

Comment: I need to know what is the cms you are using ? And maybe if you are not a developper we will need to chat on facebook or something, because it could me long to explain you everything, and this is not the point here. Check in my profile here, you'll find my email.